# Azure DevOps: ever increasing number of attached work items on each merge

Tags: git, azure-devops, devops, git-flow

We're currently using Git flow on **Azure Devops** in the usual setup with `master`, `development`, and `release-xx` branches with their respective feature and hotfix branches.

Every week a new RC gets branched of `development`, is designated `release-xx` with an incrementing number and is deployed automatically on the test environment via AZ devops.

When this RC is validated and good to go for production, its merged via a PR to `master`. After the merge to `master`, `master` once again is merged into the new RC, development etc. `master` goes on to be deployed on the production environment.

This seems to work fine, however DevOps attaches an increasing amount of work-items in every production release. So the work-items that are *already* deployed in production are attached again, while they have not being linked in new commits or PR's. This process repeats itself, so the amount of user stories is every increasing...

Thoughts about this? Are we merging incorrectly? Am I missing some step in the process? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Azure DevOps git PRs accumulate work items on each merge. In this case, you can clear all work items on the merge back from the master branch.

[image]

On our projects, we use builds to automatically create PRs from the master branch without linked work items. Here is the PowerShell script to create PR to some target branch (`development` in your case): https://github.com/ashamrai/AzureDevOpsExtensions/blob/master/CustomPSTasks/CreatePRBuildTask.ps1

Comment: Any idea how I can clear the work items without using a PR? This merge back is usually done via direct commit push - although I suppose I could use a PR in the future.

Comment: @rumblefx0 At present, it is the most convenient way to remove work item links through pull request.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Ok, thnx!